# What compensation can be claimed in case of a road accident resulting death in Denmark?

Tags: death, accident, compensation, denmark

The victim was on the way to work in a cycle, travelling in the cycle lane when got hit by a truck and died immediately.

What compensation would the family be entitled to and claim (either from offender’s insurance or the State)?

Comment: If there is a claim for compensation, the party liable to the victim (or in this case the victim's successors) will be the offender, not the offender's insurer.  Whether the insurer will cover any of that liability is between the insurer and the offender.